# How can I retrieve JSON data from an external URL and manipulate it using PHP?

Tags: php, json, get

I need to retrieve data from the following URL:
    http://lt.ff.ryanair-bilietai.lt.eturas.lt/flights/webservices/lowest/?limit=50&print=0&way_type=one_way

I need to show all departures cities, name with price, from "departureCity":"Kaunas" and format that data as a list,

The list would look something like this:

```
<ul>
 <li>City Price</li>
 <li>Vilnius 59 Lt</li>
</ul>
```

What is needed to actually pull the JSON data from the external URL?
Once pulled how do I manipulate that data so a list can be generated?

Comment: Hi Thomas and welcome to Stack Overflow! You may be wondering why your question is being down-voted. You may want to review the ["How to Ask" page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and keep those points in mind when asking in the future. Also remember it is appropriate for you to mark the best answer as the "accepted answer" to give back to the person who helped you out, in this case Jamal Khan.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of how you can get the data from the json source:

```
   $jsonData = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://lt.ff.ryanair-bilietai.lt.eturas.lt/flights/webservices/lowest/?limit=50&print=0&way_type=one_way"));
 echo "<ul>";
 foreach($jsonData as $key=>$value){
       if($value->departureCity == "Kaunas"){
              echo "<li>" . $value->priceAdult . "</li>";

       }
 }
echo "</ul>";
```

This will print all the city prices originating from Kaunas. For more info, use this after line 1:

> print_r($jsonData);

Comment: I have modified it to meet your exact requirements.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
 <?php
    $data = file_get_contents("http://lt.ff.ryanair-bilietai.lt.eturas.lt/flights/webservices/lowest/?limit=50&print=0&way_type=one_way");

    $jsondata = json_decode($data);

    // this will print array you can play with it now

    print_r($jsondata);
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the data from url like this:

```
$limit = $_GET["limit"];
$print = $_GET["print"];
$way_type = $_GET["way_type"];
```

These are the values from the url string, you can use them to search from the database or any data source you want.

Comment: Maybe you can paste the full code with the getting url and printing results?

Comment: I don't know which is your datasource and is it formated, but to use the above data in a database, you can do something like this:

`$conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
$db = mysql_select_db("mydatabase", $db);
$res = mysql_query("Your database query goes here");
echo "<ul>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($res)){
echo "<li>" . $row->price . "</li>";
echo "<li>" . $row->name . "</li>";
}
echo "<ul>";
`

Comment: I dont need a mysql connection. My website already work i need a code to get data from url

Comment: To print the data you get from the url you can use this:  
`
echo "<ul>";  
echo "<li>" . $_GET["limit"] . "</li>";  
echo "<li>" . $_GET["print"] . "</li>";  
echo "<li>" . $_GET["way_type"] . "</li>";  
echo "<ul>";  
`  
This code might be far from what you actually need but this is how you get the data from the url.

Comment: Oh you want to get the data from the json source you provided, I'll provide the solution in another answer. this comment thing sucks.